# Write Array with List to csv

Tags: f#

I have an array with multiple lists inside and want to write the values to an CSV
unfortunately I cannot figure out how to write the Array.mapi.

Any ideas?

```
   let temp = [|title;body;ordinariePris;extraPris;inkopPris;images;allValues|]

   let lines2 = 
            temp 
            |> Array.mapi (fun idx (t,b,op,ep,ip,i,av) ->
                sprintf "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s" title body ordinariePris extraPris inkopPris images allValues
                       )
        let header = "title\tbody\tordinariePris\textraPris\tinkopPris\tallValues"
        
        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("test.csv", 
            Array.append [| header|]lines2, Encoding.UTF8)
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that `mapi` indexes over the elements of `temp`, which means that you're only getting one column at a time.  You want to retrieve one row at a time.

The following instead transposes your list of lists, so that indexing does what you want.  It's also a little more generic-- you don't actually need to know the number of columns ahead of time.  It does, however, assume that every column has the same number of elements in it.

```
let col1 = ["a"; "b"; "c"]
let col2 = ["1"; "2"; "3"]
let col3 = ["x"; "y"; "z"]

let cols = [col1; col2; col3]

let transpose(xs: string list list) : string list list =
  [0 .. xs.[0].Length - 1] |> List.map (fun i ->
    xs |> List.rev |> List.fold (fun acc col -> col.[i] :: acc) [] 
  )
  
let stringify_rows(xs: string list list) : string list =
  xs |> List.map (fun row -> System.String.Join(",", row))
  
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("test.csv", cols |> transpose |> stringify_rows)
```

Note that this approach does not use an array of lists, since there was no obvious reason that you had to use an array. `WriteAllLines` will happily accept any `IEnumerable`.

If you do a lot of CSV writing, I recommend using a library like [CsvHelper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper), since correctly handling when to quote or escape cell contents can be tricky.

Comment: Thank you. this almost work, but when im adding the list into the columns it gives me :

all elements must be of the same type as the first element, witch here is 'string' . This element has type 'string * string list'

Comment: For this to work, each column (each list) must only contain `string` elements.  In other words, a column is a `string list`.  The type error you supplied is telling you that you have a pair of elements (a tuple), one of which is a string and the other of which is a list of strings.  So your input is malformed.

Comment: exactly what is happening.